# Matrix dimensions do not agree with bsxfun function

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to find the maximum value of `TpAf` (the function in `bsxfun`) for a given set of `(a,b)` when  `X` varies from 1 to 2, and `Y` varies from 0 to 1. Further, I want to find corresponding `X` and `Y` values.

I tried by creating matrix `TpAf` for different possible `(X,Y)` pairs. But I have Matrix dimensions problem in my matlab code.

Can someone please help me to correct this?

```
function HyAf
clear all
hvar=0.1:0.2:1; hl=length(hvar);
hfix=1.1*ones(1,hl);
a=hvar; b=hfix;
HybAfAvar = zeros(hl,4);
HybAfAvar(:,1) =hvar; 
stepX=0.2; X0=1.1; X=X0:stepX:1.8;  
stepY=0.1; Y0=0.1; Y=Y0:stepY:1; 

for k=1:hl
    TpAf = bsxfun(@times,log(1 + (2*a(k).^2*b(k)*(1 - 1./X).*(2./Y - X))./(1 +2*a(k)*(1 - 1./X) + a(k)*b(k)*(2./Y - X))).',Y./2);
    [HybAfAvar(k,2), ind] =max(max(TpAf)); 
    [i, j] = ind2sub(size(TpAf),find(TpAf==HybAfAvar(k,2)));
    HybAfAvar(k,3)=Y0+(i-1)*stepY; 
    HybAfAvar(k,4)=X0+(j-1)*stepX; 

end

HybAfAvar
```

Please note that `stepX` and `stepY` can be different and I may change these values in to very small such as 0.0001 if my code works well.

Comment: Running the first part of your code, the number of elements in `Y` is 10 while that of `X` is 4.  You are performing arithmetic operations in the second input of `bsxfun` assuming that `Y` and `X` are the same size but they aren't.  Unfortunately I have no idea on what that statement is trying to calculate to give you further insight, but you get that dimension error because you have at least one variable that doesn't match in size.  Right off the bat, `X` and `Y` mismatch in size and you are performing a subtraction between these two variables as part of the arithmetic statement in param 2.

Comment: I just want to know how I can change TpAf  in order perform for different sizes of X and Y.

Comment: OK. I think I know what you want to do... suffice it to say, you don't need `bsxfun`.  Let me write an answer.

Comment: I thought that if I can use bsxfun, the computational complexity or running time might be less rather than using few for loops. Thanks rayryeng !!!

Comment: No problem at all.  Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem statement correctly, you wish to create a matrix `TpAf` where each location in this matrix has a unique `(X,Y)` pair that is used to calculate an entry in this matrix.

Your use of `bsxfun` is unfortunately incorrect.  `bsxfun` can only be used if the dimensions of two arguments `A` and `B` have the ability to be broadcasted.  This means that when you match each dimension up for `A` and `B`, they both have to match or one of them has to be 1.  In your current setup, this unfortunately isn't the case.  `X` is a 10 element array and `Y` is a 4 element array.  The second parameter to `bsxfun`, namely `A`, has some statements where `Y` is being subtracted by `X` and MATLAB will flat out give you an error because there is a dimension mismatch.  When subtracting two arrays, you must be sure that both variables being subtracted match in size.

In addition, the `B` argument is a scaled version of `Y` and that is also 4 elements.  These two facts are why you are getting a dimension mismatch.  What I recommend you do instead is to manually generate a grid of 2D coordinates for each possible `(X,Y)` then apply the equation using this grid.  The output will finally be a matrix which you can apply to the rest of your code.  [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) is a logical choice here.

BTW, using `clear all` at the beginning of your code is superfluous.  Because this is a function script, all variables declared within the scope of this function are contained within and so every time you call this function, the variables within the scope of this function get cleared any way.

Now, back to your `meshgrid` situation, using your code, I would do this instead:

```
stepX=0.2; X0=1.1; 
stepY=0.1; Y0=0.1; 
[X,Y] = meshgrid(X0:stepX:1.8,Y0:stepY:1);
```

Doing this gives us:

```
>> X

X =

    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000
    1.1000    1.3000    1.5000    1.7000

>> Y

Y =

    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000
    0.2000    0.2000    0.2000    0.2000
    0.3000    0.3000    0.3000    0.3000
    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000    0.4000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000    0.5000
    0.6000    0.6000    0.6000    0.6000
    0.7000    0.7000    0.7000    0.7000
    0.8000    0.8000    0.8000    0.8000
    0.9000    0.9000    0.9000    0.9000
    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

As you can see, each spatial position gives us a unique `(X,Y)` pair, starting at the top left which gives us `(X,Y) = (1.1,0.1)` and down to the bottom right, which gives us `(X,Y) = (1.7,1.0)`.

`X` and `Y` are now compatible in dimension and you can go ahead and calculate the matrix.  Once that's corrected, the calculation of your matrix can just be with simple arithmetic element-wise operations.  In addition, if I can provide an additional comment, the way you're finding the `(X,Y)` location of the maximum value is a bit inefficient.  I'd use a call to `find` then index directly into your `X` and `Y` matrices once you call `max`.

Here's the code corrected with what I talked about above:

```
function HyAf

hvar=0.1:0.2:1; hl=length(hvar);
hfix=1.1*ones(1,hl);
a=hvar; b=hfix;
HybAfAvar = zeros(hl,4);
HybAfAvar(:,1) =hvar; 

%// Change
stepX=0.2; X0=1.1; 
stepY=0.1; Y0=0.1; 
[X,Y] = meshgrid(X0:stepX:1.8,Y0:stepY:1);

for k=1:hl
    TpAf = log(1 + (2*a(k).^2*b(k)*(1 - 1./X).*(2./Y - X))./(1 +2*a(k)*(1 - 1./X) + a(k)*b(k)*(2./Y - X))) .* (Y./2); %// Change
    HybAfAvar(k,2) = max(max(TpAf));  %// Change
    [i,j] = find(TpAf == HybAfAvar(k,2), 1); %// Change
    HybAfAvar(k,3) = Y(i,j); %// Change
    HybAfAvar(k,4) = X(i,j); %// Change
end

HybAfAvar
```

The first line in the loop calculates `TpAf` for all possible pairs of `(X,Y)`.  Once we find this, we figure out the maximum value of `TpAf` then figure out which location in our 2D grid generates this maximum value.  We then use this spatial location and index into our `X` and `Y` matrices to actually extract out the `(X,Y)` value that generated the maximum.

When I run the above code, I get this for my output:

```
HybAfAvar =

    0.1000    0.0041    0.4000    1.7000
    0.3000    0.0223    0.5000    1.7000
    0.5000    0.0446    0.6000    1.7000
    0.7000    0.0683    0.6000    1.7000
    0.9000    0.0916    0.6000    1.7000
```

Comment: Thanks rayryeng !!! I have checked answers with my numerical values which are calculated using mathematica, matched well. Your code is faster as well even I changed stepX=0.0002 and stepY=0.0001....  saved my time :)

Comment: @Frey - My pleasure!  I'm glad the calculations matched up with Mma.  Good luck!